# What is the tail strike pitch angle of the ATR-72?

Tags: tail, atr-72

What is the maximum pitch attitude an ATR-72 can be during takeoff or landing, without having a tail strike?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [FCOM](https://aviation-is.better-than.tv/atr72fcom.pdf) says "tail strike may occur if pitch attitude exceed 8° during the flare
depending upon vertical speed at touch down" (Ctrl + F "tail", matches 31 and 32).